# How do I install Email::Send::Gmail for ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, activeperl

I am trying to install that module for mail sending .

And i am getting following errors :

```
Warning: Prerequisite 'IO::Socket::SSL => ' for 'CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz'
 failed when processing 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO'
. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm blib\lib\Net\SMTP\SSL.pm
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/test.t ..
#   Failed test 'use Net::SMTP::SSL;'
#   at t/test.t line 2.
t/test.t .. 1/1 #     Tried to use 'Net::SMTP::SSL'.
#     Error:  Can't locate IO/Socket/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Perl\cpan
\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Jh6RtD\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Jh
6RtD\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SS
L-1.01-Jh6RtD\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Jh6R
tD\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/test.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'test_dynamic'
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Running make for L/LB/LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\Email-Send-Gmail-
0.33-G8YCrU

  CPAN.pm: Going to build L/LB/LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'Net::SMTP::SSL => 0' for 'LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.
tar.gz' failed when processing 'CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz' with 'make_test
=> NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/Email/Send/Gmail.pm blib\lib\Email\Send\Gmail.pm
  LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/pod.t .. skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD: Can't locate Test/P
od.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Perl\cpan\build\Email-Send-Gmail-0.33-G8YCrU\bl
ib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\Email-Send-Gmail-0.33-G8YCrU\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/li
b C:/Perl/lib) at (eval 4) line 2.
Files=1, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.03 CPU)
Result: NOTESTS
  LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (Net::SMTP::SSL)
  LBROCARD/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I tried to install IO::Socket::SSL but there also i got alot of errors

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks for help. When I try to install Net::SMTP::SSL I get the following errors:

```
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Cannot determine perl version info from lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
Cannot determine license info from lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
*** Could not find OpenSSL
    If it's already installed, please set the OPENSSL_PREFIX environment
    variable accordingly. If it isn't installed yet, get the latest version
    from http://www.openssl.org/.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
]
  FLORA/Net-SSLeay-1.35.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Running make for S/SU/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.3
1-q3PROh

  CPAN.pm: Going to build S/SU/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'Net::SSLeay => 1.21' for 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz
' failed when processing 'FLORA/Net-SSLeay-1.35.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => N
O 'C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512'. Cont
inuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp SSL.pm blib\lib\IO\Socket\SSL.pm
  SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01loadmodule.t ........... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\bui
ld\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PRO
h\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/01loadmodule.t line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01loadmodule.t line 14.
t/01loadmodule.t ........... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 4/4 subtests
t/02settings.t ............. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\bui
ld\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PRO
h\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/02settings.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/02settings.t line 4.
t/02settings.t ............. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t ...... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\bui
ld\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PRO
h\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/acceptSSL-timeout.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/acceptSSL-timeout.t line 3.
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t ...... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/auto_verify_hostname.t ... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/auto_verify_ho
stname.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/auto_verify_hostname.t line 4.
t/auto_verify_hostname.t ... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/cert_no_file.t ........... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/cert_no_file.t
 line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/cert_no_file.t line 14.
t/cert_no_file.t ........... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/compatibility.t .......... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\bui
ld\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PRO
h\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/compatibility.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/compatibility.t line 5.
t/compatibility.t .......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/connectSSL-timeout.t ..... no testlib at t/connectSSL-timeout.t line 3.
t/connectSSL-timeout.t ..... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/core.t ................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/core.t line 6.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/core.t line 6.
t/core.t ................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/dhe.t .................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/dhe.t line 11.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/dhe.t line 11.
t/dhe.t .................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/inet6.t .................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/inet6.t line 5
.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/inet6.t line 5.
t/inet6.t .................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t .. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/memleak_bad_ha
ndshake.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/memleak_bad_handshake.t line 6.
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/nonblock.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/nonblock.t lin
e 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/nonblock.t line 6.
t/nonblock.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/readline.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/readline.t lin
e 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/readline.t line 14.
t/readline.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/sessions.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/sessions.t lin
e 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/sessions.t line 5.
t/sessions.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/start-stopssl.t .......... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\bui
ld\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PRO
h\blib\lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at t/start-stopssl.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/start-stopssl.t line 4.
t/start-stopssl.t .......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/startssl.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/startssl.t lin
e 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/startssl.t line 6.
t/startssl.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/sysread_write.t .......... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/sysread_write.
t line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/sysread_write.t line 9.
t/sysread_write.t .......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/verify_hostname.t ........ Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Socket-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\IO-Sock
et-SSL-1.31-q3PROh\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at t/verify_hostnam
e.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/verify_hostname.t line 4.
t/verify_hostname.t ........ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01loadmodule.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 4 tests but ran 0.
t/02settings.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/auto_verify_hostname.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/cert_no_file.t         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/compatibility.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/connectSSL-timeout.t   (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/core.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/dhe.t                  (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/inet6.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/nonblock.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/readline.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/sessions.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/start-stopssl.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/startssl.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/sysread_write.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/verify_hostname.t      (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=18, Tests=0,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.08 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.08 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 18/18 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Running make for C/CW/CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01
-Qu1Nlt

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CW/CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'IO::Socket::SSL => ' for 'CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz'
 failed when processing 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO'
. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm blib\lib\Net\SMTP\SSL.pm
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/test.t ..
#   Failed test 'use Net::SMTP::SSL;'
t/test.t .. 1/1 #   at t/test.t line 2.
#     Tried to use 'Net::SMTP::SSL'.
#     Error:  Can't locate IO/Socket/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Perl\cpan
\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Qu1Nlt\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Qu
1Nlt\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SS
L-1.01-Qu1Nlt\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-Qu1N
lt\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/test.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'test_dynamic'
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Sorry that i paste not as code just couldnt manage to do so .

I imtalled it now but i am still getting errors

```
Warning: Prerequisite 'IO::Socket::SSL => ' for 'CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz'
 failed when processing 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.31.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO'
. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm blib\lib\Net\SMTP\SSL.pm
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib',
 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/test.t ..
#   Failed test 'use Net::SMTP::SSL;'
t/test.t .. 1/1 #   at t/test.t line 2.
#     Tried to use 'Net::SMTP::SSL'.
#     Error:  Can't locate IO/Socket/SSL.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:\Perl\cpan
\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-94zxyS\blib\lib C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-94
zxyS\blib\arch C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SS
L-1.01-94zxyS\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Perl\cpan\build\Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01-94zx
yS\blib\lib/Net/SMTP/SSL.pm line 8.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 4) line 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/test.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'test_dynamic'
  CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CWEST/Net-SMTP-SSL-1.01.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

How you paste code like a code ?
Sorry i paste it bad again .

Comment: Looks like you need to install OpenSSL, see openssl.org.

Comment: If you want to make something look like code, select the whole block, and press Ctrl-K .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you use ActivePerl 5.8.8. [Add trouchelle.com repository](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl). Do

```
ppm install IO-Socket-SSL
```

It may also work for version 5.10. List of other repositories is available [here](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=PPM_Repositories) and if you ppm is fresh enough in "Options".

Comment: +1 because adding trouchelle.com repository is probably what the OP needs to know.

Answer (score 3):

How are you trying to install this? It looks like you are trying to do it by hand, which means you have to handle all of the dependencies yourself. It looks like you are using ActiveState, so use the [ppm](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Downloads/ActivePerl/PPM/) tool to do that for you (see [the ppm FAQ](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html)).

```
 C:/> ppm install IO::Socket::SSL
```

Gmail uses a secure channel for mail, so you need SSL. This is a moderately long line of dependencies leading back to a non-Perl library. As such, it's not something you want to do by hand. Again, let the `ppm` tool do it for you.

You can see the chain of Net::SMTP::SSL and IO::Socket::SSL. You'll also need [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay) which needs the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) library.

If you have trouble with `ppm`, post another question and tells us the version of ActivePerl that you are using, etc., and show us your `ppm` config file.

If you don't particularly care about ActivePerl, you can also use [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com), which allows you to use the common CPAN toolchain. It comes with a C compiler and the other supporting tools. You still need to install OpenSSL, but after that it's just a call to `cpan`:

```
 % cpan IO::Socket::SSL
```

Note that you can't necessarily mix ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl compiled libraries. They might use different C compilers and those binaries might have different structures and requirements. See the comments for details and be careful about which compiler you use.

Comment: It is possible to mix compilers. `ppm install gcc` install gcc for ActivePerl :)

Comment: That still doesn't make the libraries compiled with different compilers interoperate, though, does it?

Comment: @brian d foy: if the gcc in question is mingw, it uses the visual C runtime and so plays nicely with activestate compiles.  a cygwin-compiled library, on the other hand, will pull in the cygwin C runtime (etc) and will not work reliably when linked to things non-cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problems with Email::Send::Gmail. I wanted to setup a simple script to get my server to send me a mail at startup/shutdown. I initially chose Email::Send::Gmail because perl was already installed on the server, but I ran into the dependency hell you describe (to which I found no easy solution, i.e. I had to install different modules one by one and I did not find a simple way to make this installation procedure reproducible, which was one of my requirements).

I ended using [sSMTP](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp) instead. I followed this tutorial explaining [how to install and configure it for use with a GMail account](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/10/21/sending-email-from-your-system-with-ssmtp/).

Comment: By using `PAR::Packer` wouldn't your dependency problems go away?

Comment: There are PPMs available: see http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/search?query=Email%3A%3ASend%3A%3AGmail&mode=module

Comment: I do not know PAR:PAcker. My server runs Ubuntu and I am used to using apt-get to install software. I found it quite hard to install perl modules on the other hand.

Comment: @Eric Bréchemier: I usually look through the dependencies and install any possible with apt-get, and only then let cpan build any remaining dependencies.  The "quite hard" part of that is that non-Perl dependencies are only documented, not automatically pulled in.  You either need to read the documentation to see what needs to be installed, or get errors and then look up what package the missing include or library files are in.